# To many simultaneously "Get" request results in 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, apache2

im using apache2 and nginx as proxy with a wordpress site. i have a plugin where user gets their own url and can download a file.

the problem:

sometimes 80+ users are requsting URLs at the same time and this results in a 500 error. It seem to work when its arround 30-40 request at the same time resulting with 200 code.

example of log file with the error:

```
IP - - [28/Apr/2019:01:00:31 +0200] "GET /test/test.zip HTTP/1.0" 500 512 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0"
```

i have a 8GB VPS and have set php.ini memory limit to 1024 and also tried to increase the timeout limit in apache2 config. what setting did i miss?

this is config for apache2

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers          8
MinSpareServers       5
MaxSpareServers      20
ServerLimit         400
MaxClients          400
MaxRequestsPerChild 4000
```

```
Timeout 60
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 10
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

Comment: Check your web servers error log and see what the actual error message is. Without that, it's impossible for us to know where to even begin. Btw, why are you using both nginx and apache? Why not just use nginx to serve the site directly?

Comment: added the example of logfile but there is not much to go from, since it works for 30-40 GET request at the same time there must be a limit or setting somewhere?

i dont know if wordpress and script will work without htaccess

Comment: WP works fine with nginx if you just configure the server config correctly. There are plenty of examples if you just google something like "nginx config for wordpress" or similar. I would recommend starting with that since Apache doesn't perform as well as nginx when you get many simultaneous requests.

Comment: thanks! i will check it and possible migrate. for now is there any setting i can change to improve it?

Comment: Without knowing what the actual error message is, any answer here would just be wild guesses. You need to do some more debugging to find that out. Currently, the question is unfortunately too broad and unspecific. However, I would recommend sorting out the web server issue (and just use nginx) first since it might actually solve your problem. If it doesn't, it might still be easier to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

@Magnus is right. Without log file to trace, it will very likely be a wild guess.

I do realize something that could be helpful. As per stated, you are running Nginx as proxy to Apache. Hence, instead of looking into Apache, perhaps you should be looking into Nginx instead. You will be able to find Nginx proxy parameter in :

```
/etc/nginx/proxy_params
```

And inside the file, you will find some standard proxy parameters like these :

```
client_max_body_size 100M; client_body_buffer_size 1m; proxy_intercept_errors on; proxy_buffering on; proxy_buffer_size 128k; proxy_buffers 256 16k; proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k; proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k; proxy_max_temp_file_size 0; proxy_read_timeout 300;
```

Try to increase the limits within the settings. You will able to find what each of them mean from [Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) itself.

Hope it helps !

*Remember to reload / restart the service.